# Discord.py application did not respond

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I try to make embeds with slash commands on discord.py rewrite and it just simply says that application did not respond

I tried making a slash command with EMBED output. I expected it to just send the embed as usual but. It said that Application did not respond

```
@bot.tree.command(name="avatar", description="avatar show lol")
async def avatar(ctx:discord.Interaction, member:discord.Member):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Avatar", description=f"{member.mention}'s avatar!", color=discord.Color.random())
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.message.author.name}", icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar)
    await ctx.response.send_message(embeds=[embed])

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} commands")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name ="what"))
    print(f"Bot account: {bot.user}")
    print(f"{discord.__version__} is lib ver")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the parameter `embeds` to `embed`.
Also try to remove the `[]` around embed, this makes it so the embed is passed as a list.

```py
await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

Comment: I tried doing it and i also used (embed=embed) it still says that application did not respond

Comment: Try to change ctx.response.send_message to interaction.response.send_message

Comment: i tried that also but its the same (ctx is discord.Interaction) its like a different name but its still the same

Comment: No, `embeds=` has to be a list of `Embed`. Alternatively, you can use `embed=` a single `Embed` object, but `embeds=[embed]` should work or `embed=embed` should work, either way.

Comment: yeah though it didnt work